# Something wrong with PyQt5 menuBar

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, pyqt5, menubar

There were something wrong when I was using PyQt5 to build a GUI window with a menu bar.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QAction, QApplication

class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        bar = self.menuBar()              

        example1 = QAction('Exit', self)        
        example1.setShortcut('Ctrl+E')
        example1.triggered.connect(self.close)

        example2 = QAction('xit', self)        
        example2.setShortcut('Ctrl+A')
        example2.triggered.connect(self.close)

        example3 = QAction('Quit', self)        
        example3.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        example3.triggered.connect(self.close)

        fileMenu = bar.addMenu('File')
        fileMenu.addAction('NNN')
        fileMenu.addAction(example1)
        fileMenu.addAction(example2)
        fileMenu.addAction(example3)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Menu Example')    
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I run this, the menu bar looks like this:

[image]

As the picture shows, 'Exit' and 'Quit' disappeared, but the shortcut worked.

My Env: Python 3.6.5, PyQt 5.11.1， MAC_OS 10.13.5

Comment: It shows up on Windows, but i don't know about Mac

Comment: Works fine in Ubuntu 16.04, Python 3.5.2 and PyQt 5.10.0

Comment: Works in Ubuntu 18.04 with Python 3.6.5 and PyQt 5.10.1 as well.

Comment: Based on comments, it seems like it is a Mac-specific issue. You may need to get ready to file a bug report in their issue tracker.

Comment: Fine on Ubuntu 16.04: https://framapic.org/kbUxJUA6bo1m/iOlbFwAp99hf.png

Answer (score 1):

The qt site says the following

> Note: Do not call QMainWindow::menuBar() to create the shared menu
>   bar, because that menu bar will have the QMainWindow as its parent.
>   That menu bar would only be displayed for the parent QMainWindow.

Try to change `bar = self.menuBar()` to `bar = QtGui.MenuBar()`

see reference form [here](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qmenubar.html#qmenubar-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in my issue there is only one window, not a shared menu bar. Maybe just like @code_dredd said, it's a MAC-specific issue.